# How do I create an instance of an interface to use as an argument to another class' constructor?

Tags: java, object, interface

I got to classes and an interface. There is one class that implements the interface but that same class uses objects of the interface.

```
   public interface Function {

        public double eval(double valueIndependentVariable);
    }

public class PiecewiseFunction implements Function {

    private Function left;
    private Function right;
    private double boundary;

    public PiecewiseFunction(Function left, Function right, double boundary) {
        this.left = this.left;
        this.right = this.right;
        this.boundary = this.boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public double eval(double valueIndependentVariable) {
        if (valueIndependentVariable < boundary) {
            return left.eval(valueIndependentVariable);
        } else {
            return right.eval(valueIndependentVariable);
        }
    }

}
```

As you see there are two `Function` objects used but how do I create those if I want an instance of `PiecewiseFunction`?

```
public class Functie {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // how do I declare foo and bar?
        Function graad = new PiecewiseFunction(foo, bar, 33);
        System.out.println(graad.eval(26));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _how do I create those_? Just like any other object. Get a class that implements the interface and instantiate it. Then pass a reference to the instance to your `PiecewiseFunction` constructor.

Comment: I created a class I could use to instantiate but I get a NullPointerException..

Answer (score 0):

You could use any other class that implements Function:

```
class Foo implements Function
{
   private double boundary;

   public Foo(double boundary)
   {
      this.boundary = boundary;
   }

   @Override
   public double eval(double valueIndependentVariable)
   {
      // add implementation here
   }
}
```

So your example could look like this:

```
public class Functie 
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Function foo = new Foo(10.0);
       Function bar = new Foo(12.0);
       Function graad = new PiecewiseFunction(foo, bar, 33);
       System.out.println(graad.eval(26));
   }
}
```